# How to split non-letter string only?

Tags: javascript

We can split the string like

```
var hello = 'my_string'; 
hello.split('_')[1]; // gets string
```

But how could we split any character not containing [a-z] or [A-Z] letter. I mean there may be `!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,+,.` etc. anything.

So how could we do?

```
hello.split('???here????')
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the `.split()` accepts a regular expression you can do

```
hello.split(/[^a-zA-Z]+/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add reg expression

```
hello.split(/[!$#_^]/)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What you want is a regular expression

[Click on to see a working example using the string in the question!](http://jsfiddle.net/5jkv5/)

Click the link to see the Regular Expression at work.
[`hello.split(/[\W_]/gm);`](http://regex101.com/r/pG3iA4) will do the trick!

- `([\W_])/gm` 1st Capturing group `([\W_])`
- `[\W_]` match a single character present in the list below `\W` match any non-word character `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- _ the literal character `_`
- `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
- `m` modifier: multi-line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Comment: `g` is redundant here